# GPU usage below 90% = poorly optimized game

Tags: optimization, pc

*Ok so not exactly a "development" question but highly related.*

When I play games I often look at performance numbers, like CPU usage, GPU usage, memory usage and others. Let us talk about GPU usage on PC. Here is my observation: there are two kinds of games:

- MAX GPU usage: these games produce **either** 60 FPS **or** 90%+ GPU usage.
- POOR GPU usage: these games produce **less** than 60 FPS **and** **less** than 90% GPU usage at the same time

MAX GPU examples (trying to make sure my idea is understood ok):

- 50 FPS, 100% GPU
- 60 FPS, 90% GPU
- 60 FPS, 50% GPU (also legit)

POOR GPU examples:

- 30 FPS, 60% GPU (FPS limit is 60)
- 40 FPS, 50% GPU

It appears that MAX GPU games use GPU efficiently to provide best performance while POOR GPU games are bottlenecked for some reason. U get few FPS, low GPU load and none of CPU cores reach 100% load. I checked and re-checked my PC many times and I don't see any specific issue which could make some games perform poorly, besides other games reach 90%+ GPU usage with no problem. Also I am not the only person who observed such behaviour.

So the question is: *POOR GPU games are poorly optimized, either on purpose or because of lack of effort.* True or false?

Also, it appears that MAX GPU games are probably multithreaded? I suspect that poor-gpu games go like this: use main thread

```
loop
  update;
  draw;
```

while max-gpu games go like this: use two threads

```
loop
  start-update in another thread; 
  start-draw;
  wait & synchronize
```

It is of course more complex than that but the general idea is basically that max-gpu games render stuff and update stuff at the same time; that is how higher GPU usage is achieved.

Ideas? Thoughts? Thanks

Comment: You're asking several questions at once and rather broad ones at that. Also you're missing another key component here, which is the CPU. If you have 50% CPU *and* GPU load and don't get 60 FPS, then obviously somethings wrong. But the CPU could also be the unit that throttles the framerate.

Comment: The correct answer is: "it is not that simple". Judging from your question you have no clue how complex the program performance problem is and you probably did no research no this topic yet.

Comment: Sorry I decided to close the question (there were 4 close votes already). as wondra mentioned there is no simple answer to this question, it can't be answered generally for any game. It **might** be answered given a certain example with the source code.

Comment: GPU load% is a pretty useless metric. It does not tell you if the problem is a memory bottleneck or compute, or simply no problem exists at all and the workload is just not particularly demanding. Better to actually measure frametime consistency and ignore load%.

Answer (score 0):

> POOR GPU games are poorly optimized, either on purpose or because of lack of effort. True or false?

It's not that simple and depends a lot on the game.

Most (if not all) games render and update at the same time, that is one of the advantages of using a GPU.

The CPU transfers memory from system RAM to graphics RAM and tells the GPU to go to town on it while it goes around and does other stuff.

It's the transfer that stops GPU usage since it can only wait for it to be finished.

The memory is transferred through a parallel bus in the GPU at a set speed. The width of the bus and the transfer clockspeed of cards creates a maximum transfer rate and this rate can be a lot slower then the CPU causing it to wait as well.

How can you solve this?

- Better graphics card
- Transfer memory less frequently
- Transfer less memory

There are more factors that play into it but the memory is the main reason usage and fps can be low.

Comment: "that is the entire point of using a GPU". no it's not. The GPU is a SIMD device while the CPU is a SISD device. You render using the GPU because it's faster. What you describe is using another CPU or core.

Comment: @BenediktS.Vogler You're missing my point. The questioner seems to be under the impression that updating and drawing are done serially. I pointed out that with dedicated hardware you do it in pararrell.

Comment: seems legit since it correlates with another observation: it often happens that both FPS and GPU usage drop when there are a lot of objects visible. U would expect GPU usage to go up when it has to draw more objects, but it's the opposite; but why? perhaps because the objects get "stuck" while being transferred from RAM to GPU RAM ?

Comment: @hinst if both drop then something is terribly wrong (@bummzack did mention this in a comment at your question already). The only cases when this can happen is when you load something from disk.